# SPListTemplate not found via Event Receiver in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a custom site template which activates a feature with an event receiver, the only thing that receiver does is to activate some other features, all in the same receiver.

The first feature I activate is a ListTemplate called "Audits".
In the third feature I activate, I try to use that template via the object model, however it isn't found, so it throws an exception.

I tried to update the site with a `web.Update()` but that didn´t work either.

The code doesn´t work when its activated via the site template, that means, if I activate my feature from an already created site, it works fine.

Is there a way to access the ListTemplate when the site is created¿?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: This is the main feature

```
/// <summary>
    /// Evento disparado al activar la feature
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties"></param>
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        //Obteniendo el sitio (web) en donde fue activada la feature
        SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;

        //Guid a utilizar para instalar las features
        Guid g;

        //GUID de Feature de list template de auditorías
        g = new Guid("{3b91e461-e8c9-49dd-857a-671eb031017c}");
        if (web.Features[g] == null)
            web.Features.Add(g);

        //GUID de Feature Catalogos
        g = new Guid("{d102dd61-0aaf-4a18-8bcc-2260e78cc87c}");            
        if (web.Features[g] == null) 
            web.Features.Add(g);

        //GUID de Feature Content type de auditorías
        g = new Guid("{a5c3defb-bcbf-41e5-aefc-2617814d25d6}");
        if (web.Features[g] == null) 
        web.Features.Add(g);

        //GUID de Feature CheckList template
        g = new Guid("{63fa11ba-e8e2-414d-bb7e-a3cdbce11cfe}");
        if (web.Features[g] == null) 
        web.Features.Add(g);

        //GUID de Feature asocia eventos
        g = new Guid("{bbc32500-034d-4d9e-a048-558d62edfe53}");
        if (web.Features[g] == null)
            web.Features.Add(g);

        //GUID de Feature para crear preguntas
        g = new Guid("{ee66eb41-57a4-400a-9c50-8db0e6beeb80}");
        if (web.Features[g] == null) 
        web.Features.Add(g);

        //GUID de Feature para ECB
        g = new Guid("{9bbdb06c-4ea1-4328-8b3d-828ea2043d3e}");
        if (web.Features[g] == null) 
        web.Features.Add(g);

        //GUID de Feature para hallazgos
        g = new Guid("{acfdda27-58d5-4f7e-a6de-0a7fe190bc74}");
        if (web.Features[g] == null)
            web.Features.Add(g);

        //GUID de Feature para resultados
        g = new Guid("{a9a804dd-18a3-47a0-80bf-25e785a8cac8}");
        if (web.Features[g] == null)
            web.Features.Add(g);

    }
```

The first feature is the list template.
The third feature has a receiver in which i look for the template

```
//Obteniendo el template
        SPListTemplate ltAuditorias = sitio.ListTemplates["Auditoria"];
```

However, I get an Index out of range exception, because it's not found.
As I said, it only happens when the main feature is activated via the site template in the Feature tag.
If I create a Blank site and then activate the main feature, everything works.

Thanks

Comment: You may need to post some code for us to get a better idea of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is probably not fully provisioned at the time your feature receiver is fired. This means not all site elements (e.g. the list templates) are available.
As a workaround you could implement a [provisioning provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebprovisioningprovider.aspx).

> The SPWebProvisioningProvider lets you take control of the SPWeb (Web site) or SPSite (Site Collection) that your are provisioning. Instead of just using a Site Template and the changes that can be applied through a Site Template you can add your own custom code to the solution.

from [The mystery that is SPWebProvisioningProvider](http://blogs.technet.com/b/apurdon/archive/2008/02/05/the-mystery-that-is-spwebprovisioningprovider.aspx).